# trim() on .collect::<String>() E0716 in Rust

Tags: rust

Rust code:

```
let item_discount_price = item_discount_price_element.text().collect::<String>().trim();
```

give error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:64:35
   |
64 |         let item_discount_price = item_discount_price_element.text().collect::<String>().trim();
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                                   |
   |                                   creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
65 |         let item_discount_price = item_discount_price.trim();
   |                                   -------------------------- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived valu
```

I have solved it with following code:

```
let item_discount_price = item_discount_price_element.text().collect::<String>();
let item_discount_price = item_discount_price.trim();
```

For background I am doing some web-scraping, item_discount_price_element is ElementRef from scraper. https://docs.rs/scraper/latest/scraper/element_ref/struct.ElementRef.html

**Question is why first code is not working ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [`trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) you'll notice that it's not a member of `String` but of `str`:

```
pub fn trim(&self) -> &str
```

That is, it takes a `&str` (string slice) and returns another `&str`, a subslice, with the same lifetime.

Now, your code is equivalent of doing something like:

```
let s: &str = String::from(" hello ").trim();
```

That would create a temporary `String`, borrow it as a `&str`, and compute its trim slice. Then the temporary is dropped and the trimmed slice reference is invalidated. Fortunately Rust lifetime rules prevents you from trying to use that invalid value.

If you save a temporary value in a variable you avoid dropping it, as you noticed in your code.

```
let s: String = String::from(" hello ");
let s: &str = s.trim();
```

And now the code does what you want.

If you do not need to ever use the temporary it is idiomatic in Rust to use the same name for both values, to illustrate that point, and to avoid having to think of two names (naming things is hard). Note that the first `s` still exists, it is not destroyed by having another variable with the same name, it is just *shadowed*, and it will be dropped normally at the end of its scope.

Comment: just if somebody else come to this: item_discount_price_element.text().collect::<&str>().trim(); can be done so to collect to &str instead of String.

Comment: @WebOrCode: Are you sure about that? I've never seen a `collect::<&str>()` and I don't know how it could work, as `&str` does int implement `FromIterator`.

Comment: here is sample code https://gist.github.com/rust-play/563d7a86312369130fce5ac75ae812e4

Comment: @WebOrCode: Unfortunately `scraper` is not available in the Playground. Anyway I tried in a local project and it fails with "value of type `&str` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>` ... required by this bound in `collect`", as expected.

Comment: to be honest I am not sure did it ever worked or I was just confused after may iterations of code. I few day I will delete cometns not to confuse others.